# Factor 9 terms with 3 variables into 4 expression

Tags: matrices, polynomials, factoring

I just got the determinant from a 4x4 matrix and the simplified version is below.
$$
det(M) =  \begin{vmatrix}
2k-mw^2 & -k  & 0 & 0 \\
-k & 2k-mw^2 & -k  & 0 \\
0 & -k & 2k-mw^2 & -k  \\
0 & 0 & -k & 2k-mw^2\\
\end{vmatrix} 
$$
the polynomial I got after 1 hr is:
$$
5k^4 - 6k^2mw^2 + 6k^2m^2w^4 - 8k^3mw^2 + 2km^2w^4 - 4km^3w^6 - 3m^3w^6 + m^4w^8 - k^2m^2w^4
$$
I want to factor this out, I tried so many ways but just gave up.

Now I know, since it was defined in Physics that the system I am studying would produce 4 normal frequencies.
Usually, the form appear as:
$$
(k-mw^2)(3k-mw^2) \\
$$
(the example above is for 2x2 matrix, hence produces 2 normal frequencies)

which is very easy to solve for $ w $.

Please help, I just want to equate the whole equation to zero and get w.

Comment: the solution is very complicated, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+5k%5E4+-+6k%5E2mw%5E2+%2B+6k%5E2m%5E2w%5E4+-+8k%5E3mw%5E2+%2B+2km%5E2w%5E4+-+4km%5E3w%5E6+-+3m%5E3w%5E6+%2B+m%5E4w%5E8+-+k%5E2m%5E2w%5E4%3D0

Comment: damn it, I wish theres nothing wrong with my determinant result, or else I just wasted my time.

Comment: the determinant is incorrect

Comment: Notice $$\det\begin{bmatrix}b&1&0&0\\1&b&1&0\\0&1&b&1\\0&0&1&b\end{bmatrix}
= b^4-3b^2+1 = U_{4}(b/2)$$ 
where $U_{n}(x)$ is the 
[Chebyshev's polynomial of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). Similar thing happens if your matrix is a $n \times n$
one instead of $4 \times 4$. Using the relation $$U_{n}(\cos\theta) = \frac{\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta}$$
you can express all the possible roots of $w$ using trigonometric functions easily.

Comment: Sir, I want to use your formula, but without the Chebyshev since it is another concept, and the w's will be used as eigenvalues (which I think will give me more hard time?), $ b^4 - 3b^2 + 1 $ since it seems that $ b = 2k - mw^2 $ but how about the $ -k $ elements? only equate to 1?

Comment: You set $b$ to $\frac{2k-mw^2}{-k} = \frac{mw^2}{k}-2$. Your determinant will be a $k^4$ times the one I wrote down. Since you only want a root, that constant factor doesn't matter. For $n = 4$, you can factor $b^4 - 3b^2 + 1 = 0$ directly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you studying something related to strings? The $\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ terms in the solutions look like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke's_law#Harmonic_oscillator

Comment: @obinna Sir, yes sir. trying to get the Normal Frequency and Normal Modes of mass-spring couple, this case 4 equal masses 5 identical springs.

Comment: I guessed so. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of the matrix given is:
$$(5 k^2-5 k m w^2+m^2 w^4) (k^2-3 k m w^2+m^2 w^4)$$

So, solving for $w$ in the equation $(5 k^2-5 k m w^2+m^2 w^4) (k^2-3 k m w^2+m^2 w^4)=0$ yields the following solutions (assume $m \ne 0)$:

$$w = \pm\sqrt{\frac{(3+\sqrt{5})}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$
$$w = \pm\sqrt{\frac{(5+\sqrt{5})}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$
$$w = \pm\sqrt{\frac{(3-\sqrt{5})}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$
$$w = \pm\sqrt{\frac{(5-\sqrt{5})}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make things a bit nicer to look at.  Let's substitute $x = 2k - mw^2$:

$$
det(M) =  \begin{vmatrix}
x & -k  & 0 & 0 \\
-k & x & -k  & 0 \\
0 & -k & x & -k  \\
0 & 0 & -k & x\\
\end{vmatrix} 
$$

I calculate the determinant to be $x^4 - 3k^2x^2 + k^4:$

$$
det(M) =  x\begin{vmatrix}
x & -k  & 0 \\
-k & x & -k  \\
0 & -k & x\\
\end{vmatrix} + k\begin{vmatrix}
-k & -k  & 0 \\
0 & x & -k  \\
0 & -k & x\\
\end{vmatrix} \\
= x^2\begin{vmatrix}
x & -k  \\
-k & x\\
\end{vmatrix} + xk\begin{vmatrix}
-k & -k  \\
0 & x\\
\end{vmatrix} -k^2\begin{vmatrix}
x & -k  \\
-k &x\\
\end{vmatrix} \\ = x^4 - x^2k^2 - x^2k^2 - x^2k^2+ k^4 \\
= x^4 - 3k^2x^2 + k^4. 
$$

Using the quadratic formula on $x^2$ gives

$$x^2 = \frac{(3 \pm \sqrt{5})k^2}{2} = (2k - mw^2)^2.$$

Now take square roots of both sides, isolate $w$, and square root again, tossing the imaginary roots as you go along.

Comment: I keep trying to solve for determinant, mine is $ x^4 - 2k^2x^2 - k^2x $ what do you think sir?

Comment: it is $k^4-3 k^2 x^2+x^4$

Comment: We can actually use wolfram alpha for this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%7B%7Bx%2C-k%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B-k%2Cx%2C-k%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-k%2Cx%2C-k%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-k%2Cx%7D%7D

Comment: Dang, there are a lot of minus signs to keep track of.  Thanks.